# Passing Selected Grid rows to next view in marionette

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a Grid in my first view , once i select some rows in the Grid and click next , the selected row data should get displayed in the next view. How to implement this requirement. I am new to backbone and marionette. Iam able to get the selected data from the below code

```
var selectedData = [],
    selectedIndexes;

selectedIndexes = grid.getSelectedRows();
$.each(selectedIndexes, function (index, value) {
    selectedData.push(grid.getDataItem(value));
});
```

where selectedData is coming as Object array and when i tried to set to model property of view object , it is giving error.

Kindly let me know how to pass the data and access it in the next view.

Answer (score 0):

Events is very nice concept that allow to make solid and independent components in your application. It is core of Backbone.

So in you case you have Grid - `CompositiomView`(`CollectionView`) that represents collection of model. Each model is rendered in its own `ItemView` - row in the grid. Using [View.triggers](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#viewtriggers) you can trigger event in `ItemView` when it is clicked:

```
Row = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  // ...

  triggers: {
    "click": "clicked"
  }
});
```

After that `CompositiomView`(`CollectionView`) [automatically retriggers event of his child](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#itemview-event-bubbling-from-child-views) views itself with prefix `itemview`. So you can listen to this event directly on `CompositiomView`(`CollectionView`). It is better to do in some [Mediator](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2013/03/18/event-aggregator-andorvs-mediator-a-tale-of-two-patterns/) that will know about both views.

It should look like:

```
var gridView = new GridView({collection: collection});

gridView.on('itemview:clicked', function(itemView){
  var someView = new SomeView({model: itemView.model});
  secondRegion.show(someView);
});

firstRegion.show(gridView);
```

Comment: I am using ItemView for displaying grid and i can select multiple rows in my grid. As i told on click on Next button in my first view i am able to retrieve the selected rows and i am getting it in the form of object array like[object, object]. I cannot assign the object array to the model property of the view directly and i have to pass these values to the third view not the immediate next view. I am still confused.

Comment: Why do you try to "assign the object array to the model property of the view directly"? First of all it is more convenient to view's model be Backbone.Model but not array of objects.

Comment: Can you please share some example on how to pass multiple selected rows using checkbox to another view and it in different grid.